# Megamenu using same category URL for all categories on front-end

Tags: magento2, category, megamenu

I'm using the Magedelight Megamenu for Magento 2.2.7

I have a range of product categories listed under the "Default Category", about 8 or 9. The Megamenu is using the URL of the first category in the list on the front-end for the URL for all of the other links, does anyone know why this could be?

Many thanks

Comment: did you overwrite the template? Magedelight does provide support FYI

Comment: I haven't overwritten the template